# Using Matlab to make modification to a text file

Tags: matlab, opencv

Essentially I am writing a Matlab file to change the 2nd, 3rd and 4th numbers in the line below "STR" and above "CON" in the text file (which is given below and is called '0.dat'). Currently, my Matlab code makes no changes to the text file.

**Text File**

```
pri  
3  
len 0.03  
vic 5 5  
MAT  
1 147E9 0.3 0 4.9E9 8.5E9  
LAY  
1 0.000125 1 45  
2 0.000125 1 0  
3 0.000125 1 -45  
4 0.000125 1 90  
5 0.000125 1 45  
WAL  
1 1 2 3 4 5  
PLATE  
1 0.005 1 1  
STR  
1 32217.442335442 3010.34241024889 2689.48842888812  
CON  
1 2 1 2 3 1 3 4 1 4 5 1 5 6 1 6 7 1   
ATT  
1 901 7 901  
LON  
34  
POI  
123456  
1 7  
X 0.015  
123456  
2 6  
X 0.00381966011250105 0.026180339887499  
123456  
3 5  
X 0.000857864376269049 0.0291421356237309  
123456  
4  
X 0  
PLO  
2 3  
CRO  
0  
RES  
INMOD=1  
END
```

**Matlab code**:

```
impafp = importdata('0.dat','\t');
afp = impafp.textdata;

fileID = fopen('0.dat','r+');
    for i = 1:length(afp)
        if (strncmpi(afp{i},'con',3))
            newNx = 100;
            newNxy = 50;
            newNy = 500;
            myformat = '%0.6f %0.9f %0.9f %0.9f\n';
            newData = [1 newNx newNxy newNy];
            afp{i-1} = fprintf(fileID, myformat, newData);
            fclose(fileID);
       end
    end
```

Comment: Your code never writes any data to the file because no fprintf or equal is included.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not too sure I understand. I thought that my use of fprintf in the 4th last line would overwrite text that was previously written at the line i-1.

Comment: You are right, I misread the code. Assigning the number of written bytes to your cell containing the text content somehow confused me.

Comment: I tried out your code, it reads only the first line to `afp`. Does it read every line on your pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help for `importdata`:

> For ASCII files and spreadsheets, importdata expects to find numeric
>       data in a rectangular form (that is, like a matrix).  Text headers can
>       appear above or to the left of numeric data.  To import ASCII files
>       with numeric characters anywhere else, including columns of character
>       data or formatted dates or times, use TEXTSCAN instead of import data.

Indeed, if you print out the value of `afp`, you'll see that it just contains the first line. You were also not performing any operation that was writing to a file. And you were not closing the file ID if the `if` state wasn't triggered.

Here is one way to do this with [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) (which is probably faster too):

```
% Read in data as strings using textscan
fid = fopen('0.dat','r');
afp = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','');
fclose(fid);

isSTR = strncmpi(afp{:},'str',3); % True for all lines starting with STR
isCON = strncmpi(afp{:},'con',3); % True for all lines starting with CON

% Find indices to replace - create logical indices
% True if line before is STR and line after is CON
% Offset isSTR and isCON by 2 elements in opposite directions to align
% Use & to perform vectorized AND
% Pad with FALSE on either side to make output the same length as afp{1}{:}
datIDX = [false;(isSTR(1:end-2)&isCON(3:end));false];

% Overwrite data using sprintf
myformat = '%0.6f %0.9f %0.9f %0.9f';
newNx = 100;
newNxy = 50;
newNy = 500;
newData = [1 newNx newNxy newNy];
afp{1}{datIDX} = sprintf(myformat, newData); % Set only elements that pass test

% Overwrite old file using fprintf (or change filename to new one)
fid = fopen('0.dat','w');
fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n',afp{1}{1:end-1});
fprintf(fid,'%s',afp{1}{end}); % Avoid blank line at end
fclose(fid);
```

If you're unfamiliar with logical indexing, you might read [this blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

Comment: Thanks horchler. The code works are required, but the output in the text file does not contain any line breaks. Do you know how this could be rectified? Thanks

Comment: @Jojo: Which output in which text file are you referring to? Are you saying that the data in `afp{1}` doesn't have `'\n'` line breaks in it? It's not supposed to as `textscan` strips those out. Do you want them?

Comment: Or are you saying that the edited file has been mangled somehow so that it's all on one line? If that happened, then something may need to be changed in how `textscan` reads the data. I tested this by copy/pasting your demo data into a file and it worked fine (you may have tabs rather than spaces that got converted when you posted your question here). It might also be a line ending issue (are you on Windows?). Try changing this line to `fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n',afp{1}{1:end-1});` (added `'\r'`).

Comment: Thanks. The `\r` rectified the problem. Sorry to keep hounding you about this, but may I just ask what this line:                    `datIDX = [false;(isSTR(1:end-2)&isCON(3:end));false];` does and how you know that afp has dimensions 1 by end as in Mathworks it is stated that "the textscan function returns a K-by-1 MATLAB numeric vector to the output cell array, C, where K is the number of times that textscan finds a field matching the specifier." Thanks a lot

Comment: @Jojo: You're confusing the dimension of the cell array with the dimensions of the contents of the cell array. For example `a = {1:4}` creates a 1-by-1 cell array (`size(a)`). `a{1}` contain a 1-by-4 numeric array (`size(a{1})`). Because `textscan` is set to match only one string (`'%s'` + no delimiters) per line, the cell array will be 1-by-1 and contain as many elements as there are rows. I'll try to edit my question to explain the `datIDX = ...` line.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just reading the entire file in, finding which lines contain your "keywords", modifying specific lines, and then writing it back out to a file, which can have the same name or a different one.

```
file = fileread('file.dat');
parts = regexp(file,'\n','split');
startIndex = find(~cellfun('isempty',regexp(parts,'STR')));
endIndex = find(~cellfun('isempty',regexp(parts,'CON')));
ind2Change = startIndex+1:endIndex-1;
tempCell{1} = sprintf('%0.6f %0.9f %0.9f %0.9f',[1,100,50,500]);
parts(ind2Change) = deal(tempCell);


out = sprintf('%s\n',parts{:});
out = out(1:end-1);
fh = fopen('file2.dat','w');
fwrite(fh,out);
fclose(fh);
```

Comment: No loop needed – just use `fprintf` to write a cell array to a file.

Comment: I also think [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) might be a more efficient choice that using regex in this case. It should work for cells too. By the way, I wasn't aware of [`fileread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html) before (it appears to be a simple front-end to [`fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html)), so thank you.

Comment: @horchler `strfind` does not seem to be more efficient (tested with simple `tic` and `toc`). Either way though for small enough files, the difference is negligible (100 microseconds or so). I also just recently learned of `fileread` and it seems to work great.

Comment: Thank you for your help MZimmerman6. I tried running your code, but I seem to come across the following error "The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side." for line 6. Would you know why this is? Thanks

Comment: yes I do know why this is happening. When I submitted my answer it was under the assumption that only one line would occur between STR and CON, and it seems as if this is not always the case. I have modified the code above to use the deal command which will assign the same value to multiple outputs in the event `ind2Change` contains multiple values.